# Am I wrong about the swift misleading doc?

Tags: swift

for the Array method:

```
@inlinable public func index(_ i: Int, offsetBy distance: Int, limitedBy limit: Int) -> Int?
```

the Doc gives an example:

```
///     let numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
///     if let i = numbers.index(numbers.startIndex,
///                              offsetBy: 4,
///                              limitedBy: numbers.endIndex) {
///         print(numbers[i])
///     }
```

why it uses `numbers.endIndex` for the `limit` param, it obvious wrong, we should use `numbers.endIndex-1`, it works here because the `distance` param is 4, and it will crash if the `distance` is 5.

I think this is a bad example, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, that would crash if distance is 5, which makes the example misleading. You should file a bug report for the documentation.

Comment: I agree it's a bad example – there's also another one for `Collection`'s documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3017684-index

Comment: A quick grep shows that there are similar (bad) examples in Array.swift, ArraySlice.swift, BidirectionalCollection.swift, Collection.swift, RandomAccessCollection.swift, StringCharacterView.swift.

Comment: @MartinR [and ContiguousArray.swift](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/2f7917696f1d8e52229359688b90eaa2) :)

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, that code does not protect against an “Index out of range” error.  `endIndex` is the array’s (or generally, collection's) “past the end” position: it is a valid index, but an invalid subscript.

For non-negative offsets,

```
if let i = numbers.index(numbers.startIndex,
                         offsetBy: offset,
                         limitedBy: numbers.endIndex), i != numbers.endIndex {
    print(numbers[i])
}
```

would be a safe variant. For arrays you can also use `numbers.endIndex-1` as the limit. That does not work for arbitrary collections though, because not all collections are indexed by integers (`String` is a good example.)

You can also check if `offset < numbers.count`, but note that accessing the `count` of an arbitrary collection can be a O(N) operation.

Another variant is

```
if let num = numbers.dropFirst(offset).first {
    print(num)
}
```

which works for arbitrary collections. As in the previous examples, a possibly *negative* offset must be excluded separately.

You can also use

```
if numbers.indices.contains(index) {
    print(numbers[index])
}
```

for safe a subscripting. That works for arbitrary collections if you keep in mind that collections indices are not necessarily zero-based, and not necessarily integers.

Comment: Or for any `BidirectionalCollection` limit by  `index(before: endIndex)`